# Where on earth am I?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I have always wanted to travel around the world.  So I quitted my job at *Malt* Traders.  When I told my friends *Toni*, *Mark* and *Gary* about my plan, they were like "*No way*!"  I knew they would love to travel with me to the *many* places that I would visit, but sorry, I had to do this alone.

Anyway, I managed to visit all these beautiful places on my bike, even though sometimes it was such a *pain* to get up in the morning, especially with the *rain*.  Some of the places I stayed at cost an *arm* and a leg.  I was not too happy about that, but at least they did not *ban* my bike and felt very much like my old place near the *port* back home.

One day, I rode past a frozen lake and saw a bunch of kids *ice* skating.  At a distance, I noticed a *larus* flapping its wings.  I have never seen one in real life before, so I got off my bike and *ran* after it.  I hoped I did not provoke the *ire* of the parents who was looking on.  Ignorance is the *key* here.  When I finally stopped and checked my pedometer, I have already ran 2319 steps.  I looked around but could not see anyone anywhere any more.  I think I am lost.

> Where have I been *and* more importantly, where on earth am I?!

Comment: Does this point towards the lyrics of a song?

Comment: No, this does not require any knowledge of songs.

Comment: No way! (I just heard about your plan)

Comment: @MarkN, What happened to Toni and Gary? :p

Comment: Come to think about it, @f" answered the question better than what I had intended. So I'll mark the answer as correct. I'll need some improvement when writing the next puzzle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The italicized words are fragments of

> European country names,

so you have been to:

- > *Malt*: Malta
- > *Toni*: Estonia
- > *Mark*: Denmark
- > *Gary*: Hungary
- > *No way*: Norway
- > *many*: Germany
- > *pain*: Spain
- > *rain*: Ukraine
- > *arm*: Armenia (not strictly in Europe, but is a member of the Council of Europe)
- > *ban*: Albania
- > *port*: Portugal
- > *ice*: Iceland
- > *larus*: Belarus
- > *ran*: France
- > *ire*: Ireland
- > *key*: Turkey

Where are you now?

> *and*

There are

> several countries in Europe that contain "and": Andorra, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Finland, Iceland (already visited), Ireland (already visited), the Netherlands, Poland, and Switzerland.

Comment: Well done.  And you've put them in the order they appeared in.  Oops, I forgot about all those countries have "and" in it.  My intended answer was Andorra. You can have that one for free.  As for "where I am now", the number of steps I took is relevant to the list of places I've been. I may or may not be in a country I've already visited. *hint* *hint*

Comment: @Eli If this is 2319 meters above sea level, this could be [Mt. Velický štít](https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velick%C3%BD_%C5%A1t%C3%ADt) in Slovakia. If feet are used (however you travel Europe), this is 706 m, lots of mountains apply

Answer (score 3):

A Guess,
As per your question and description.

> I rode past a frozen lake and saw a bunch of kids ice skating. At a distance, I noticed a larus flapping its wings.

- > You can see Larus in Norway (As per [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larus))

> even though sometimes it was such a pain to get up in the morning

- > Sometime you can see SUN at even on midnight at North Norway. so may be you feel pain when you wake up at morning (Sometime there is no SUN on morning) due to your body still not set his biological clock.

> I hoped I did not provoke the ire of the parents who was looking on.

- > *ire* is Middle English Word (īra) (As per [This Link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ire), South Norway)

> When I told my friends Toni, Mark and Gary about my plan, they were like "No way!" I knew they would love to travel with me to the many places that I would visit, but sorry, I had to do this alone.

- > I took common char. "**R**" from your 2 friends name and place it in their like "**No way**". It would become "**No*r*way**"

So My guess, you are in

> **Norway**